# How to solve for t in exponential function

Tags: exponential-function

I have the following function :
$be^{-at} -ae^{-bt} =0.5(b-a)$ where b and a is know and I want to solve for t. I tried several ways to simplify it but still cannot find a way to get $t$. Any suggestion will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Let $x=e^{-t}$ and you will get a polynomial of generic degree.  Such polynomials usually cannot be solved in general.  However, the result here looks oddly symmetric, so there may be a possibility...

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt:  what if $a$ or $b$ is not an integer or natural number?

Comment: @RobertLewis Then that's even worse to solve :-)

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt:  true enough!

Answer (score 0):

**hint**

divide by $ab $ to get

$$\frac {e^{-at}-0.5}{a}=\frac {e^{-bt}-0.5}{b} $$